# What is this long free arm machine called?

Tags: sewing-machine, tool-identification

This post about sewing tubes without a presser foot or feed dogs suggests using a specialized machine.

What is the second machine in [Elmy's answer here](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/a/5908/6388) called?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

"Feed-off-the-arm sewing machines – A feed off the arm sewing machine’s design is unusual in that its arm bridges a u-shaped bed. Such machines are ideal for seaming the inseams of pants and jeans as well as the sides, sleeves, and shoulders of shirts."

https://www.abcsewingmachine.com/blogs/features/62525253-the-different-types-of-industrial-sewing-machines-body-design

Comment: And in the OP's case, a three- or triple needle one.

Comment: @Joachim for my purposes I really want a generic home machine (lockstitch, zig zig) with a really long arm.  Several models are available as well as cylinder bed, lockstitch, zig zag units.